# Meaning of two-people icon on folders

Tags: directory

What does this folder icon, with the image of the two people, mean?

[image: Folder with a blue two-people icon.]

Comment: Shared dropbox folder?

Comment: @Jean-Marie I'm sure it's a shared folder icon but not in dropbox as the op suggests its from Gnuplot

Comment: Yes, you're right! It's a shared Dropbox folder. I had seen the symbol on folders that apparently weren't shared, but I found they were shared with another account of mine. The folder "Gnuplot" that I showed was just an example; there are lots of folders with different names and this image.